# JPA/Hibernate: How to associate composite foreign keys with partial primary keys

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two tables, each with a composite key:

```
CREATE TABLE Software (
  id int not null,
  version int not null,
  PRIMARY KEY (id, version)
);

CREATE TABLE System (
  name char(10) not null,
  version int not null,
  PRIMARY KEY (name, version)
);
```

Now, I need an association where I can express the concept "a Software has minimum requirements on the version of the System where it can run". The following table does it at the DB level:

```
CREATE TABLE Requirement (
  software_id int not null,
  software_version int not null,
  system_name char(10) not null,
  system_version int not null,
  PRIMARY KEY (software_id, software_version, system_name),
  FOREIGN KEY (software_id, software_version) REFERENCES Software (id,version),
  FOREIGN KEY (system_name, system_version) REFERENCES System (name,version)
)
```

Note that Requirement has three fields as primary key. If I were to make all four primary, then I could express more than one requirement for a software (i.e OpenLib v1.2 depends on Ubuntu 13.04 and on Ubuntu 13.10), whereas a software can only have one requirement for a given OS (in the example, OpenLib v1.2 depends on Ubuntu 13.04).

How can I map this to JPA/Hibernate @Entity objects (using annotations)? (Including the related OneToMany/ManyToOne associations.)

The main problem I'm facing is the fact that only part of the System's key is used as Primary key in Requirement.

Note: I don't have to abide to a specific legacy database, so the database design can be modified.
I am also open to both @EmbeddedId and/or @IdClass solutions. I would prefer compliance with JPA though.

The properties, in my code, need to be mapped through getter/setter, not directly through the fields, but I guess solutions using fields only are fine, as long as the conversion is straight forward.

Thank you.

**** EDIT 28/8/2014 ****

Consider the following simple test scenario that I am using to test the solutions given:

```
Software software = new Software(1,10);
System system = new System(2,20);
session.save(software);
session.save(system);
Requirement req = new Requirement();
req.setSoftware(software);
req.setSystem(system);
session.save(req);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can code `Requirement` class as follows:

```
@Entity
public class Requirement {

    @EmbeddedId
    private RequirementKey id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "name", referencedColumnName = "name", 
                        insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "system_version",
                        referencedColumnName = "version",
                        insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
    private System system;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id", 
                        insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "version", 
                        referencedColumnName = "version",
                        insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
    private Software software;

}
```

with `RequirementKey`:

```
@Embeddable
public class RequirementKey implements Serializable {
    int id;
    int version;
    String name;
}
```

I think there is better solution, but I cannot figure out how it may be done.

Comment: Will not work: Both system and software variables refer to the same column "version" in the DB. Note that there are 4 columns in Requirement, and the two "version"s are different.

Comment: @Filippo So, is your point to have four columns in `Requirement` or three? My code above assumes that you want to have three columns (each belonging to requirement PK) and it works so under Hibernate 4.3.5 and JPA 2.1.

Comment: Four total. Three are PK, one is not. Of the four columns, two are FK for Software, two are FK for System. The column named system_version is not part of the PK, but it is in the system (and is different from software_version). See the SQL statements for the DB layout.

Comment: @Filippo take a look at the update, now it generates `Requirement` table with four columns of which three are PK

Comment: Will try. Though I'm puzzled by the "insertable=false,updatable=false" in the system_version join column definition. Would hibernate insert the value? I'm afraid it may leave the column empty...

Comment: take a look at my edit with a simple insert scenario. When I try to execute using your solution, it tries to perform a query with 5 elements bound: "insert 
    into
        Requirement
        (software, system, id, version, name) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)>". The first two are of type VARBINARY (according to the logger). This ends up in a table with 5 columns generated by Hibernate...

Comment: @Filippo have you regenerated schema?

Comment: yes, the schema is generated automatically at test startup from the model.